# Python Conditional Statements DataFrames

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have the following code in Python, I need to write a conditional statement in which bd_día has a new "cuenta" that is not Filtro_dia, in that case a new row has to be added with the new "cuenta" and "new value."

I am not a programmer, I am learning Python. Hope somebody could help me.

Here is the code:

```
type here

lista_datos = []
for i in range(bd_dia.shape[0]):
  # print(i)
  if list(bd_dia["cuenta"])[i] in list(Filtro_dia["Cuenta"]):
    lista_datos.append(Filtro_dia.iloc[i])
    lista_datos[i][7] = bd_dia["ValorTotal"].iloc[i]
  else:
  if list(bd_dia["cuenta"])[i] not in list(Filtro_dia["Cuenta"]):
    nueva_fila = 

  break;
```

Comment: Before posting, make sure your code runs.  It looks like it needs a bit of work.  "type here" is not valid Python code.  Also your indentation looks wrong after the `else:` statement.

Comment: Also, you need to provide a sample of the data.  Read this article about providing a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The opposite of `if <something>:` is the `else`, so there is no point doing `else: if <not something>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reading [ask] and [mre] will likely increase chances of getting answers. Taking the [tour] is also quite informative.